# Запрос к таблице с частичным совпадением (поиск)

Tags: mysql

Доброго дня

Есть обычная таблица в обычной бд MySQL. Хочу сделать запрос, найти всех, у кого в имени есть аша. т.е. это не точно аша, а может быть Маша, Даша, Наташа, и даже, что бы аша было по середине, но как это сделать, что бы поиск был не по точному значению, а только по части?

```
$moy_zapros = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `name`='аша'");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE '%аша%'
```

Comment: мне стыдно за вопрос, а вот за ответ спасибо.

Comment: Вопрос из прошлого века, но всё-таки решил напомнить о большых и малых буквах\символах. Такой запрос может ничего не найти если в таблице всё в верхнем регистре и не учитывается case sensetive.